# Kotlin : Do there any way to package private in kotlin?

Tags: class, intellij-idea, kotlin

In Java or Dart, we can create **package private class** that can perform only into this package. From outside this package, we can't invoke this class or this class's methods.
Do there any way to do this in kotlin?

**Note :** If I create `class kotlin_class{}` than I can't extends this class form other class in same package. I need to change it into `open class ktolin_class{}`. If I use **open** keyword here, this class can invoke from outside this package.

Comment: There are four [visibility modifiers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) in Kotlin: `private`, `protected`, `internal` and `public`.

Comment: @jaco0646 I know these modifiers. That's why I want to know do there any way to do private package in kotlin or it's a limitation?

Comment: No, there is [no package private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914095/package-protected-alternative-in-kotlin) in Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks @MichiGysel. I hope this is big limitation of kotlin.